# How to evaluate this integral with square trinomial and root?

Tags: integration, analysis

**I have to evaluate this integral:**
$$\int{\frac{1-x+x^2}{x\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx}$$
I have experience with methods such as:

- Using substitute for x;

  for example, $${\frac{1}{x}=t;dx = -\frac{dt}{t^2}}$$
- Method of adding a new variable;
- Substitution method;
- Integration by the parts.

In addition, I just need to mention, that **we have learned topic with square trinomial**.
Just remake this expression:
$${1+x-x^2}={\frac{5}{4}-(x-\frac{1}{2})^2}$$
And, of course, then we can use some formulas for evaluation, when have expression in required view. Thanks!

Comment: Hints: first remove the part $\frac 1{x\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}$ (integrates in $\tanh^{-1}$) then simplify by $x$, then remove the part corresponding to $(\sqrt{1+x-x^2})'$ then what remain integrates in $\arcsin$.

Comment: @zwim , can you explain: how to integrate into $artanh$

Comment: In fact I think there is a better way, you can try Euler second substitution $\sqrt{1+x-x^2}=ux-1$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_substitution. You'll get $\int \frac 1{2u+1}du$ for the first term. But you can also apply it to the whole integral, at the price of partial fraction reduction after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint...

You can split this into three integrals:
$$I_1=\int\frac{1}{x\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx$$
$$I_2=\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx$$
$$I_3=\int\frac{x}{\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx$$

For $I_1$, substitute $t=\frac1x$ and this leads to an $\operatorname{arcosh}$-type integral.

For $I_2$, this is an $\arcsin$-type integral.

For $I_3$, you can rewrite it as $$-\frac12\int\frac{-2x+1}{\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx+\frac12I_2$$

Can you finish this?

Answer (score 1):

$\int{\frac{1-x+x^2}{x\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx}$

The rooted is a trinomial ($a x^{2}+2b x+c$), which has two real roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, decomposing it we have:
$\sqrt{a x^{2}+2b x+c}=\sqrt{a(x-\alpha)(x-\beta)}=(x-\beta)\sqrt{\frac{a(x-\alpha)}{x-\beta}}$.
Let's say
$\frac{a(x-\alpha)}{x-\beta}=t^{2}$, and we get :

$x=\frac{a\alpha-\beta t^{2}}{a-t^{2}}$

$dx=\frac{2 a t(\alpha-\beta)}{(a-t^{2})^{2}}dt$.

Substituting these values in the integral, we have:
$\int{\frac{1-x+x^2}{x\sqrt{1+x-x^2}}dx}=$,

$=-\int{\frac{4(2t^{4}-t^{2}+2)}{(t^{2}+1)^{2}(t^{2}(\sqrt{5}+1)-\sqrt{5}+1)}dt}=$,

expanding

$=\int{\frac{2\sqrt{5}}{(t^{2}+1)^{2}}dt}$

+$\int{\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{t^{2}+1}dt}$

-$\int{\frac{4}{ t^{2}(\sqrt{5}+1)-\sqrt{5}+1)}dt}$.

Calculating the individual integrals:

$I_{1}=\sqrt{5} .tan^{-1}(t)+\frac{\sqrt{5}t}{t^{2}+1}$,

$I_{2}=(1-\sqrt{5}).   tan^{-1}(t)$,

$I_{3}=-ln(\frac{2t-\sqrt{5}+1}{2t+\sqrt{5}-1})$.

Ultimately you have:
$I=I_{1}+I_{2}+I_{3}=tan^{-1}(t)+\frac{\sqrt{5}t}{t^{2}+1}-ln(\frac{2t-\sqrt{5}+1}{2t+\sqrt{5}-1})$.

All that remains is to replace the value of $t$ with $x$:

$t=\frac{-2x-\sqrt{5}+1}{2x-\sqrt{5}-1}$,

getting the result.